# Using hyperspaces and the Fell topology to study quotient spaces

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be second countable locally compact Hausdorff space and $q:X\to Y$ a quotient map with $Y$ Hausdorff. Then the fibres $q^{-1}(y)$ are closed subsets of $X$, and hence can be regarded as points in the second countable compact Hausdorff space $Cl(X)$ of closed subsets of $X$ with the Fell topology (roughly: convergent nets have to meet open neighbourhoods and miss compact sets). Let $X_*$ be the closure of this set of points in $Cl(X)\setminus\{\emptyset\}$. Then $X_*$ is a second countable locally compact Hausdorff space and one can consistently define a map $q_*:X_*\to Y$ by $q_*(F)=q(x)$ where $x\in F$. Furthermore $q_*$ is a quotient map.

Thus one can replace $X$ and $q$ by $X_*$ and $q_*$, and $q_*$ looks more likely to have singleton or compact fibres than $q$ was.

Presumably this or something similar or better is a standard approach in studying quotient maps? I would be grateful to be pointed in the right direction.

To make the question specific: does the process stabilise? e.g. does $X_{**}=X_*$?